# Using composer to pull in Swipestripe module - requires payment module, no matching package found?

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe, swipestripe

I am trying to pull in `Swipestripe` using composer using the following command as per their instructions: http://swipestripe.com/dev/docs/swipestripe/en/Basics/Install

```
composer require swipestripe/swipestripe:2.1.*@dev
```

I am getting this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - swipestripe/swipestripe 2.1.x-dev requires silverstripe/payment 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - swipestripe/swipestripe 2.1.0 requires silverstripe/payment 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for swipestripe/swipestripe 2.1.*@dev -> satisfiable by swipestripe/swipestripe[2.1.0, 2.1.x-dev].
```

I have tried to require just the `silverstripe/payment` module 2 ways, both don't work.

```
composer require "silverstripe/payment:1.0"
```

and

```
composer require "silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-payment:1.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/payment#1.0.x-dev there is a 1.0.x dev branch you could try. What composer minimum stability have you set for your project?

Comment: I didn't have a minimum stability set. Pulling in that payment 1.0.x-dev worked though :) Thanks.

Comment: ok, i added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/payment#1.0.x-dev](http://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/payment#1.0.x-dev) there is a 1.0.x dev branch.

The according command is:

```
composer require silverstripe/payment:1.0.x-dev
```